# KeyError: "['belongs_to_collection' 'homepage' 'original_title' 'overview'\n 'poster_path' 'status' 'tagline'] not found in axis"

Tags: python, csv, data-mining, data-cleaning, sklearn-pandas

This is my data

```
     #   Column                 Non-Null Count  Dtype   
 0   belongs_to_collection  604 non-null    object 
 1   budget                 3000 non-null   int64  
 2   genres                 2993 non-null   object 
 3   homepage               946 non-null    object 
 4   imdb_id                3000 non-null   object 
 5   original_language      3000 non-null   object 
 6   original_title         3000 non-null   object 
 7   overview               2992 non-null   object 
 8   popularity             3000 non-null   float64
 9   poster_path            2999 non-null   object 
 10  production_companies   2844 non-null   object 
 11  production_countries   2945 non-null   object 
 12  release_date           3000 non-null   object 
 13  runtime                2998 non-null   float64
 14  spoken_languages       2980 non-null   object 
 15  status                 3000 non-null   object 
 16  tagline                2403 non-null   object 
 17  title                  3000 non-null   object 
 18  Keywords               2724 non-null   object 
 19  cast                   2987 non-null   object 
 20  crew                   2984 non-null   object 
 21  revenue                3000 non-null   int64  
dtypes: float64(2), int64(2), object(18)
```

I run it by python3.7, when I am trying to drop the column, it remind me that"KeyError: "['belongs_to_collection' 'homepage' 'original_title' 'overview'\n 'poster_path' 'status' 'tagline'] not found in axis""

Here is my code.

```
to_drop = ['belongs_to_collection', 'homepage','original_title','overview','poster_path','status','tagline']
data.head()
data.drop(to_drop, inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
data.drop(columns=to_drop, inplace=True)
```

[pandas DOC](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

EDIT

both ways is working here!

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.tab', sep="\t")
to_drop = ['belongs_to_collection', 'homepage','original_title','overview','poster_path','status','tagline']


data.drop(columns=to_drop, inplace=True)
#data.drop(to_drop, inplace=True, axis=1) <== working too

data.info()
```